# Rank and Dimension of Kernel for non-square matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors, matrix-rank

suppose a 7x5 matrix has B and Bx=0 has a general solution of x=$\lambda$v where v is some non-zeo vector and an element of $\mathbb{R}^5$. What's the dimension of the kernel for this matrix B and its rank?

I'm not quite sure about this but the way I interpret this is by looking at the homogenous solutions given by $\lambda$v. Does it only have one linearly independent vector as a solution which is v? So the dimension of the kernel is 1? if so, there are still infinite solutions right? So how would I get to know what the rank of this matrix is, cause I'm all confused about this and would really appreciate some guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $T: \mathbb R^5 \to \mathbb R^7$ be defined by $T(x)=Bx.$

Then $ker(B)=ker(T)= span(v)$, hence $\dim ker(B)=1.$

From the nullity - rank - theorem we derive

$$5= \dim ker(T)+ rank(T)=dim ker(B)+ rank(B)=1+rank(B).$$

Thus

$$rank(B)=4.$$

Comment: this may be a very dumb question but how do we know that the dimension of B is 5? i do know that it as to be less and equal to 5 but how do we know it is 5 in this case? I'm sorry I'm very new to this and everything seems to be a little blurry to me now. But once again i can't thank you enough.

Comment: The domain of $T$ has dimension $5$, not $B$.